# Capturing Pandas aggregation in to Lists

Tags: pandas, list, pandas-groupby

I have a column of data which has datetime and another column which has a numeric field (Length) and I am able to aggregate as below, where I am grouping by datetime and getting min/mean/max of all Lengths.

Code:

```
df.groupby(['DateTime']).agg({'Length': ['min', 'mean', 'max']})
```

Output:

```
                    Length                   
                            min         mean   max
DateTime                                          
2020-11-24 14:30:00         118  1172.712000  1505
2020-11-24 14:30:01         118  1246.719495  1508
2020-11-24 14:30:02         115  1062.351156  1508
```

I need a simple way to capture this output in a set of lists, something like this:

```
outputdatelist=[2020-11-24 14:30:00, 2020-11-24 14:30:01,...]
outputlen_min=[118, 118, 115]
```

Similarly for mean, max.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: `outputdatelist = df.DateTime.tolist()`?

Comment: @sharathnatraj, I need to capture the output of the df.groupby(....) not the individual elements of df. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: yeah i got it.. just do `df1 = df.groupby(['DateTime']).agg({'Length': ['min', 'mean', 'max']}).reset_index()` and then `outputdatelist = df1.DateTime.tolist()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say the input df is like below,

```
     DateTime  Length
0  2018-01-01     100
1  2018-02-01     100
2  2018-03-01     100
3  2018-04-01     100
4  2018-05-01     100
```

Try the code:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['DateTime']).agg({'Length': ['min', 'mean', 'max']}).reset_index()
outputdatelist = df1['DateTime'].tolist()
outputlen_min =  df1['Length']['min'].tolist()
```

Prints:

```
print(outputdatelist)
['2018-01-01', '2018-02-01', '2018-03-01', '2018-04-01', '2018-05-01']
print(outputlen_min)
[100, 100, 100, 100, 100]
```

similarly for `mean` and `max` columns.